# Indicial equation of $(x^2-1)^2y''+(x+1)y'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha>\beta$ be the roots of the indicial equation of $(x^2-1)^2y''+(x+1)y'-y=0$ at $x= -1$.

> Then what is the value of $\alpha-4\beta$  ?

I am trying to solve this by Frobenius series solution method. Assuming trial solution of the form $y=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_m(x+1)^{m+\rho}$. Then  I get the indicial equation as $$\rho^2-1=0.$$ So $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=-1$.  Thus the value of $\alpha-4\beta$ is $5$.

But the answer is $2$. The question appears in GATE 2017. So where i am wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's `y''`, not `y^{''}`

Comment: The indicial equation is $\rho^2-\frac{3}{4}\rho-\frac{1}{4}=0$.

Comment: @Wang Sir can you explain how it arise?

Comment: The indicial equation of the linear ODE $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ near the regular singular point $x=x_0$ is given by
$$
r^2+p_0r+q_0=0,
$$
where $p_0=\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)p(x)$ and $q_0=\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)^2q(x)$.

Comment: @Wang Thanks for your valuable comment. Here the indicial equation would be $r^2+(p_0-1)r+q_0=0$ and I get  the indicial equation as your previous comment.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2-1)^2y''+(x+1)y'-y=0$$
At $x=-1$
We have,
$$\alpha(x)(x+1)^2y''+\beta(x)(x+1)y'+\gamma(x)y=0$$
With$ \begin{cases} \alpha(x)=(x-1)^2 \implies \alpha(-1)=4\\
\beta(x)=1 \implies \beta(-1)=1\\
\gamma(x)=-1 \implies \gamma(-1)=-1
\end{cases}
$

Then the indicial equation is

$$r^2+\left(\frac {\beta(-1)}{\alpha(-1)}-1\right)r+\frac {\gamma(-1)}{\alpha(-1)}=0$$
$$r^2-\frac {3}{4}r-\frac {1}{4}=0$$
$$(r-1)(r+\frac {1}{4})=0 \implies r=1, r=-\frac 1 4$$

$$\text{And }\alpha -4\beta=1-4\frac {-1} 4=2$$